# Is there a function to extrude a shape along a path in cgal?

Tags: cgal

I have not found the way to do it with cgal.
Please can you point me to some functions I have to use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not exist yet in CGAL but there is a draft implementation [here](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/6317).